# HOW TO Bootstrap 5 modal right

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

How can I set the modal to the right in Bootstrap 5? I’ve seen a few answers from Google, but most of them aren’t for Bootstrap 5. On big screens, the modal should appear on the right side.

My code

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 5px; right: 5px; margin: 0px; padding: 5px 3px; z-index: 1;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#NewsModal" @click="getNews()" style="padding: 7px 11px;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-newspaper" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path
          d="M0 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1h11A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 14 2.5v10.528c0 .3-.05.654-.238.972h.738a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5H1.497A1.497 1.497 0 0 1 0 13.5v-11zM12 14c.37 0 .654-.211.853-.441.092-.106.147-.279.147-.531V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v11c0 .278.223.5.497.5H12z"/>
        <path d="M2 3h10v2H2V3zm0 3h4v3H2V6zm0 4h4v1H2v-1zm0 2h4v1H2v-1zm5-6h2v1H7V6zm3 0h2v1h-2V6zM7 8h2v1H7V8zm3 0h2v1h-2V8zm-3 2h2v1H7v-1zm3 0h2v1h-2v-1zm-3 2h2v1H7v-1zm3 0h2v1h-2v-1z"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="NewsModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="NewsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="NewsModalLabel">Yangliklar</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-12 mb-3" v-for="(item, key) in news">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="img-fluid" :src="item.photo" role="img" alt="news image" v-if="item.photo !== null">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="~/assets/images/news.jpg" role="img" alt="news image" v-else>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.name }}</h5>
                  <div class="collapse card-text" :id="'collapseExample'+item.id" v-html="item.content"></div>
                  <p class="mt-1">
                  <div data-bs-toggle="collapse" :data-bs-target="'#collapseExample'+item.id" aria-expanded="false" :aria-controls="'collapseExample'+item.id">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-up rotate180" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 5.707l-5.646 5.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6z"/>
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Yopish</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

If the screen is 1400px or bigger, the modal will be positioned to the right.

See the snippet below.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 5px; right: 5px; margin: 0px; padding: 5px 3px; z-index: 1;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#NewsModal" @click="getNews()" style="padding: 7px 11px;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-newspaper" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M0 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1h11A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 14 2.5v10.528c0 .3-.05.654-.238.972h.738a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5H1.497A1.497 1.497 0 0 1 0 13.5v-11zM12 14c.37 0 .654-.211.853-.441.092-.106.147-.279.147-.531V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v11c0 .278.223.5.497.5H12z" />
        <path d="M2 3h10v2H2V3zm0 3h4v3H2V6zm0 4h4v1H2v-1zm0 2h4v1H2v-1zm5-6h2v1H7V6zm3 0h2v1h-2V6zM7 8h2v1H7V8zm3 0h2v1h-2V8zm-3 2h2v1H7v-1zm3 0h2v1h-2v-1zm-3 2h2v1H7v-1zm3 0h2v1h-2v-1z" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="NewsModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="NewsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="NewsModalLabel">Yangliklar</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-12 mb-3" v-for="(item, key) in news">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="img-fluid" :src="item.photo" role="img" alt="news image" v-if="item.photo !== null">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="~/assets/images/news.jpg" role="img" alt="news image" v-else>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.name }}</h5>
                  <div class="collapse card-text" :id="'collapseExample'+item.id" v-html="item.content"></div>
                  <p class="mt-1">
                    <div data-bs-toggle="collapse" :data-bs-target="'#collapseExample'+item.id" aria-expanded="false" :aria-controls="'collapseExample'+item.id">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="26" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-up rotate180" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 5.707l-5.646 5.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6z" />
                      </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Yopish</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
}

Thanks for this it worked for me